# I want to Display products Through Linklist Collection?

Tags: php, shopify, shopify-app, shopify-template, shopify-activemerchant

i'v been loop through array of collections and try to get products of each collections but it is still not working ??

```
<div class="products_nav">
  {% capture collections_list %}
    {% for link in linklists[block.settings.meganav_link].links %}
        {{ link.title }}                
    {% endfor %}
  {% endcapture %}

  {% assign collections_array = collections_list  %}    

  {% for products in collections_array %}       

    {% for category in products %}
        {% for product in collections[category].products %}
            {% include 'product-grid-item' %}
        {% endfor %}
    {% endfor %}

  {% endfor %}
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

The `capture` command will capture the output of everything between `{% capture x %}` and `{% endcapture %}` as a text and assign that text to the variable `x`.  So your code:

```
{% capture collections_list %}
  {% for link in linklists[block.settings.meganav_link].links %}
      {{ link.title }}                
  {% endfor %}
{% endcapture %}
```

...will only be capturing a series of line breaks and link titles, since that's all the text that is getting printed.

What you probably want to do is get the object representing the actual item in the list.  A quick hop to [Shopify's Liquid Reference](https://help.shopify.com/en/themes/liquid/objects/link) shows us that `link` objects have a property conveniently called `object`, which references the thing that the link points to - which can be a product, collection, page or blog.

If you know that each link is going to be a collection, you can then write something like this:

```
{% for link in linklists[block.settings.meganav_link].links %}
   <h2>{{ link.title }}</h2>
   {% assign linked_collection = link.object %}
   {% for product in linked_collection.products %}
     {% include 'product-grid-item' %}
   {% endfor %}
{% endfor %}
```

If your linklist is more complicated and there's a mix of object types, you will probably want to check the `link.type` and proceed appropriately. Once again, the Shopify Liquid Reference has your back when it comes to what the different possible types are.

Hope this helps!